# Cypress - Unable to open link/anchor tag urls in Chrome

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing

I am trying to navigate to different parts of my web application by clicking on simple anchor tags via cypress using cy.click() method.

The url in the browser updates to the new url but the page load fails. It gives an error and subsequently all the following steps fail. This error is not valid cause I can manually and on Firefox navigate to this with the same steps.

I have tried to cy.wait() also tried to assert using cy.should() till an element is visible but the page itself fails to load.

If I use cy.reload() the page reloads and works fine (new url is already set in the browse).

Note: I am facing this issue only in Chrome and Electron. This is not a problem in Firefox which is surprising.

```js
cy.get("button[href='someLink']").click()
cy.reload()
```

Cypress runner New Url

[image: Cypress runner New Url]

On click in the cypress runner I can see "new url" but the redirect fails or just doesn't happen in chrome

In the console I can see New url and Url updated by: pushState

Console url update by pushState:

[image: Console url update by pushState]

Is the issue with the web app? Or is there a bug on chrome side or cypress is simply not able to route to the url?

Answer (score 0):

I found this workaround

```
 cy.get('a').then((elem) => {
      cy.visit(elem[0].href)
    });
```